# How to make the code resource URL private for SFMC use only

Tags: marketing-cloud, ssjs, security, private

I need to restrict the access of code resource endpoints to SFMC use only. Some update codes are added in SSJS which will be called from SFMC. In case the URL is exposed somehow, I don't want to have any external users accessing the same and the URL should be private.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the [authorization code flow](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/marketing/marketing-cloud/guide/integration-app-auth-code.html) to check if the user accessing the CloudPage/Code Resource url is logged in, and if not, the user will be asked to log in to Marketing Cloud using their credentials. Once the user logs in, a cookie will be set with the value of the access token.

Here’s an example script:

```
<script runat="server">
Platform.Load("core", "1");

var client_id = "xxxxx",        //add the client id from the installed package
    client_secret = "xxxxxx",    //add the client secret from the installed package
    subdomain = "xxxxx",        //add the 28 character subdomain (starts with mc….xxxx)
    redirect_uri = "xxxxx";     //add the url of the CloudPage that hosts your app

var auth = true;

var authToken = Platform.Request.GetCookieValue("authToken");
if (authToken == null) {
    var authCode = Request.GetQueryStringParameter("code");
    if (authCode == null) {
        Platform.Response.Redirect("https://&quot; + subdomain + ".auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/authorize?response_type=code&client_id=" + client_id + "&redirect_uri=" + redirect_uri);
    } else {
        var url = "https://&quot; + subdomain + ".auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token"
        var contentType = "application/json";
        var payload = {
            "grant_type": "authorization_code",
            "code": authCode,
            "client_id": client_id,
            "client_secret": client_secret,
            "redirect_uri": redirect_uri
        };
        try {
            var accessTokenRequest = HTTP.Post(url, contentType, Stringify(payload));

            if (accessTokenRequest.StatusCode == 200) {
                var tokenResponse = Platform.Function.ParseJSON(accessTokenRequest.Response[0]);
                var accessToken = tokenResponse.accessToken;
                Platform.Response.SetCookie("authToken", accessToken);
                auth = true;
            }

        } catch (error) {
            auth = false;
        }
    }
}
</script>
```

In above you’ll have to add:

- Client Id and Client Secret from an Installed Package,
- The 28 character subdomain used in your tenant-specific endpoints (eg. mcx3g7dtegr6hh7y5h7grhrgr97n),
- The URL of the CloudPage/Code Resource that hosts your app.

For more details and a full tutorial see here: https://sfmarketing.cloud/2021/08/09/securing-marketing-cloud-apps-hosted-on-cloudpages/

Comment: This is an extremely useful feature, well explained and documented by you. Thank you zuzannamj!

Comment: Great article, thanks for sharing Zuzanna!

Comment: @zuzannamj, Sorry for less explaining the context. I need to ensure that the code resource JavaScript is triggered from SFMC itself. Not by an SFMC user. If there is some method to decode JWT in SSJS, that would be enough I guess.

Answer (score 3):

The other answer is the correct one, and well explained.

I just feel this is a nice addition:

After setting your page to private / authenticated, you could also make it show up in the appExchange Menu (for specific users, too, via Installed Package Access)

[image]

Create a new package under Marketing cloud :  `Setup → Apps →  Installed packages → New`

[image]

Add a Marketing Cloud App component to  the package : `Add Component → Marketing cloud App → Next`

[image]

Set a name and description for the App.

[image]

the Name will show up in the AppExchange Menu.

Use your Cloud Page URL as login Endpoint and logout Endpoint, and Save. You’re good to go !

[image]

You might need to log out of Marketing Cloud, and log back in to see your app under AppExchange menu in Marketing Cloud.