# Can I control who has access to different sender profiles SFMC?

Tags: marketing-cloud, permissions, admin, sfmcadmin

I'd like to ensure that an Agency is only able to use sender profiles which are able ot be used for commercial sends (i.e. I have suppression rules to suppress anyone who is opted out) I do not want anyone but my transactional email team to be able to send an email using a transactional IP address.
We would all use the same business Unit though.  Is there a way to create a permission that blocks the use of non-commercial sender/delivery profiles?

Comment: I am afraid this is a limitation in MC, once you let them access and send email, then they can pick any available sender profiles

Comment: Not possible within 1 BU. The only secure way to do it would actually be to setup an extra BU for transactional sending. But this obviously depends on the importance of the matter.
Even with Approvals you would only approve the Email and not the send config.

Answer (score 1):

As the commenters say, once you give access to the email send interface and have only one BU, you are running into a UI limitation. It will show everything or nothing in a BU when it comes to Sender Profiles etc.

So it definitely cannot be done easily and depending on how much you can invest, this might just be the answer.

Just for the record - it's not absolutely impossible (and I have seen it done). There is only a *very* costly solution if you are limited to one BU:

- Do NOT give access to the standard send Interface to the relevant users/ show nothing and start from zero.
- Set up an authenticated service on a cloudpage that lets people send emails via the API, and put it into the appexchange menu as custom app.
- in that app, read out the logged in user;

[How to make the code resource URL private for SFMC use only](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/386068/how-to-make-the-code-resource-url-private-for-sfmc-use-only/386075#386075)

https://sf-marketing.com/marketing-cloud-user-validation-on-cloudpages/

https://mateuszdabrowski.pl/docs/ssjs/snippets/sfmc-cloud-page-apps/

- retrieve only those sender profiles via SOAP API for each logged in user that they "should" see (you will likely need a data extension to store this mapping)
- build a custom send process inside your app through the available APIs.

You will understand that a full solution is beyond the scope of a stackExchange post :D